# Cannot insert anything to a webpart page in SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a simple Webpart page that I have created both from the browser and from within SP Designer 2013 for a SP 2013 On-Prem site. For some reasons I am not able to insert any of the controls, forms or webparts from the ribbon menu at the top when I position my cursor in the middle of the following code. All I hear is a chime, but no code inserted. I am on Windows 7 32 bit and most uptodate with all updates:

```
<tr>
                <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate>
                **MY CURSOR IS POSITIONED HERE**
                </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
            </tr>
```